# DevExpress: Customize the XAF Scheduler List View Display Text

Tags: devexpress, scheduler, xaf

I have a business object in my XAF application which inherits from the standard Scheduler'Event' class. In the list view I get the default scheduler list view where the boxes display the descriptive text. I want to display additional text in those boxes. I looked around and found "ScheduleControl.InitAppointmentDisplayText" event but could not figure out how to implement it within my class.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the following code within a view controller within the Module.Win project.

```
namespace Project.Module.Win.Controllers{

using DevExpress.ExpressApp;
using DevExpress.ExpressApp.Scheduler.Win;
using DevExpress.XtraScheduler;

public partial class SchedulerViewController : ObjectViewController<ListView, Project.Module.BusinessObjects.Event>
{
    public SchedulerViewController()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.RegisterActions(this.components);
    }

    protected override void OnViewControlsCreated()
    {
        base.OnViewControlsCreated();

        SchedulerListEditor listEditor = View.Editor as SchedulerListEditor;

        if (listEditor != null)
        {
            SchedulerControl scheduler = listEditor.SchedulerControl;

            if (scheduler != null)
            {
                scheduler.InitAppointmentDisplayText += new AppointmentDisplayTextEventHandler(this.SchedulerControl_InitAppointmentDisplayText);
            }
        }
    }

    private void SchedulerControl_InitAppointmentDisplayText(object sender, AppointmentDisplayTextEventArgs e)
    {       
        MyEventObject myEventObject = this.ObjectSpace.GetObjectByKey<MyEventObject>(e.Appointment.Id);

        if (myEventObject != null)
        {
            e.Text = string.Concat("Text Goes Here - ", myEventObject.FieldValue);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I was not able to get access the properties of my class. e.Appointment only gives access the default 'Event' properties

Comment: View.Editor.List has the list of all the objects avaliable in the list. But View.CurrentObject always returns null

Comment: I have updated my answer for you, i have managed to get this to work showing my custom fields which i have added to my event class.